# How to restrict controllers dicovery in MVC6 for a specific assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a middleware with its own controllers.

Let's assume I have 2 assemblies : `MainAssembly` (main MVC project) and `MiddlewareAssembly` (middleware controllers).

I am trying to load the middleware's controllers on a mounted prefix only, this way `MiddlewareAssembly.HomeController` would not cause any conflict with the `MainAssembly.HomeController`.

Is there a way that I can configure the `MiddlewareAssembly` routes so that they are using a custome scheme and are not discovered automatically by the `MainAssembly` ? (best would be if this configuration would apply only for the `MiddlewareAssembly` to not interfere with any other middlewares)